# Could i use epoll on IOS/Android platfom?

Tags: android, c++, ios, select, epoll

I want to develop a cross-platform c ++ network communication library that use epoll to replace select on the mobile platform.

But I found that ios can only use kqueue, and not all android platforms support epoll, so in this seek help.

OR is there anyother Advice ?

Comment: If `boost` is supported on the platforms you're interested in then [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) might be worth a look.

Comment: I just find other efficientive methods (CURL_MULTI_WAIT) 
https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2012/09/03/introducing-curl_multi_wait/

Answer (score -2):

- No. epoll is a Linux-specific system call. you cannot use with iOS. but 
  The closest equivalent on the ***Darwin*** kernel is kqueue, but I strongly suspect that's considered SPI (and hence off-limits) on iOS

Comment: Copy and paste? what is spi mean?

Comment: could you give a relevant reference link？